# Type any has no subscript members swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

My code is this

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var young = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    callAlamo(url: young)
}

func callAlamo(url: String){

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        let responseJSON = response.data
        if responseJSON  == nil{
           print("response is empty")
        }else{
            print("Jon is \(responseJSON)")

            self.parseJson(JSONData: responseJSON!)
        }

    }
}

func parseJson(JSONData: Data){

    do{
        let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers)

        for  i in 0..<(readableJSON as AnyObject).count{
            print(readableJSON[i] as String)
        }

    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}  
}
```

[image]

I need each array element inside this Json.

Comment: There are > 20 questions about the very same error message. Please check if your problem hasn't been answered before.

Comment: Can you show me your JSON that you are getting form service?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below code:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value) :

            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value as! [String:AnyObject]!{
                print("JSON: ",JSON)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            completionHandler(APIResponse.init(status: "failure", response: nil, result:nil))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `responseJSON` handler, the `JSON` data has already been parsed internally by `JSONSerialization`. You do **NOT** want to try to parse it again, otherwise you're parsing the server's response data twice which is really bad for performance. All you need to do is the following:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("Parsed JSON: \(json)")
        // Now you can cast `json` to a Dictionary or Array
    }
}
```